# A good reference for power and Box-Cox transformation

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, references, data-transformation, boxcox-transformation

I would appreciate if someone could introduce me a good reference for power transformations and Box-Cox transformation. I'm elementary in statistics and I want to learn them properly. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: have checked the wiki article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform ?

Comment: Read the first few chapters of John Tukey's book *EDA* (Addison-Wesley 1977).  IMHO, the Wikipedia article misses the point entirely and is far too mathematical in its approach.

Comment: @whuber Thanks very much for your help and the book. I was wondering if you could help me about my question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/619534/likelihood-function-of-power-transform . Appreciate it.